# Django with Vue on sub page in history mode

Tags: django, vue.js

I have been able to render a Vue app in a Django template when the django url is `/`. But in this case we want the Django url for the Vue page to be `/dashboard`. `/` is just a static Django page.

The issue is that the Vue page is showing, but the routes do not work. When I disable history mode, the routes work fine, even on `/dashboard/#`.

So in urls.py I added these lines at the end:

```
re_path(
    "^dashboard.*$",
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name="dashboard.html"),
    name="app",
),
```

in `router.ts` I have the following configuration:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

I also tried to set `base: '${process.env.BASE_URL}/dashboard'` which didn't work either.

And `vue.config.js` has the following setup:

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  baseUrl: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080',
  outputDir: './dist/',

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization
      .splitChunks(false);

    config
      .plugin('BundleTracker')
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: '../frontend/webpack-stats.json' }]);

    config.resolve.alias
      .set('__STATIC__', 'static');

    config.devServer
      .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
      .host('0.0.0.0')
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
      .https(false)
      .headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ['\*'] });
  },
};
```

That can I do to get the Vue app running on `/dashboard` in Django?

Comment: did you figure it out yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but here's what I did to get it to work...

In your router update the base to `/dashboard/`

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/dashboard/',
    routes: [
    ...
```

In your urls.py you have to add two `path`s...

```
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='dashboard.html')),
path('<path:path>', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='dashboard.html')),
```

This will allow your router to use /dashboard/ without hitting a new url